# Double LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, zend-framework, left-join

I want to receive property name and units count and specails count. I have this query:

```
SELECT 
  `property`.`property_name`,
  COUNT(unit_id) AS `units_count`,
  COUNT(special_id) AS `specials_count` 
FROM `property`
  LEFT JOIN `property_unit` ON unit_property_id = property_id
  LEFT JOIN `property_special` ON special_property_id = property_id
WHERE (property_id = '1')
GROUP BY `property_id`
ORDER BY `property_name` ASC
```

But it is not working properly. If I have one of these left joins - it's ok, but if I have two, I get this result:

```
["property_name"] => string(11) "Rivers Edge"
["units_count"] => string(1) "2"
["specials_count"] => string(1) "2"
```

Specials count is 2 and units_count is 2, but units count is really '1'. How can I get correct counts for it?

P.S: for those who know Zend Framework:

```
$select->setIntegrityCheck(FALSE)
    ->from(
        'property',
        array(
            'property_name',
        )
    )
    ->joinLeft(
        'property_unit',
        'unit_property_id = property_id',
        array(
            'units_count' => 'COUNT(unit_id)'
        )
    )
    ->joinLeft(
        'property_special',
        'special_property_id = property_id',
        array(
            'specials_count' => 'COUNT(special_id)'
        )
    )
    ->group('property_id')
    ->order('property_name');
```

Comment: Are unit_id and special_id unique keys on the property_unit and property_special tables?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  `property`.`property_name`,
  COUNT(distinct unit_id) AS `units_count`,
  COUNT(distinct special_id) AS `specials_count` 
FROM `property`
  LEFT JOIN `property_unit` ON unit_property_id = property_id
  LEFT JOIN `property_special` ON special_property_id = property_id
WHERE (property_id = '1')
GROUP BY `property_id`
ORDER BY `property_name` ASC
```

EDIT:

You shouldn't *always* use distinct - it happens to be the right option in this case.

`select count(fieldname)` returns the number of times that fieldname is not null; `select count(distinct fieldname)` returns the number of distinct values of fieldname.

In the original query, property_unit and property_special aren't joined to each other, only to property - so for a single property that had 5 units and 7 specials, 35 rows would be returned; therefore `count(unit_id)` and `count(special_id)` would both return 35. Since there would be 5 distinct values of unit_id and 7 distinct values of special_id (*because* these fields uniquely identify their records), `count(distinct ...)` returns the correct values in these circumstances.

Comment: Very thanks, it's works!! But I can't understand why I should always use DISTINCT..

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL should be something like this:

```
SELECT 
  `property`.`property_name`,
  COUNT(property_unit.unit_id) AS `units_count`,
  COUNT(property_special.special_id) AS `specials_count` 
FROM `property`
  LEFT JOIN `property_unit` ON (property_unit.unit_property_id = property.property_id)
  LEFT JOIN `property_special` ON (property_special.special_property_id = property.property_id)
WHERE (property.property_id = '1')
GROUP BY `property.property_id`
ORDER BY `property.property_name` ASC
```